# hex-arc golang - overcome import cycling error when testing

Tags: go, importerror, hexagonal-architecture, go-testing

I am having trouble testing `foo_handler` in my Go project. My project has the following structure:

```
├── Makefile
├── cmd
│   └── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── internal
    ├── api
    │   ├── router.go
    │   └── server.go
    ├── core
    │   ├── domain
    │   │   └── foo.go
    ├── handlers
    │   ├── foo_handler.go
    │   ├── foo_handler_test.go
```

`main.go` invokes `NewApi()` from `server.go`, which in turn creates and instantiates a Router struct using the `NewRouter()` in `router.go`, which in turn creates and instantiates the `FooHandler` struct. So, in other words:

`main.go` -> `server.go` -> `router.go` -> `foo_handler.go`

I need to use `api` to establish and get a new router object to test `foo_handler`, but I get an error:

```
FAIL tmp-svc/internal/handlers [setup failed]
# tmp-svc/internal/handlers
package tmp-svc/internal/handlers
    imports tmp-svc/internal/api: import cycle not allowed in test
FAIL
```

How can I overcome this error without changing the test directory? What am I missing? If I move `foo_handler_test.go` to a `bar` directory, the test runs without any issue.

Comment: Why do you have to create a router to test FooHandler? Why not call it directly?

Comment: @Peter Can you elaborate? I have to create a router because i'm registering all the routes and in the foo_handler_test i'm trying to test against these routes with mock requests and responses

Comment: You simply call FooHandler.ServeHTTP in the test instead of the router's ServeHTTP.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I overcome this error without changing the test directory?

You cannot (in a sensible way). You can try an interface dance.

> What am I missing?

Hexagonal (or any other) *architecture* is **not** about folders but about software architecture. Somehow software architecture is considered "folder-layout" nowadays. You can put everything in one package and still have "hexagonal architecture".

Comment: My current intuition is to create dir for tests with subdirs of unit tests / integration_tests, but all guides i've read so far recommend to put test files within the same directory of the source file

Comment: @Dana Tests in Go typically belong the the package. This has nothing to do with "directories".

Comment: @Dana The main concept of Hexagonal Architecture is Dependency Invesrsion Principle. You have your Domain layer which contains all business entities and logic and ports  for implementation details, for example repository interfaces instead of implementations. Then you have Infrastructure layer, which contains adapters - implementations - of our ports. You can put it nicely to different folders, but as mentioned, it is not necesary. Its about using Dependency Inversion and not relaying on implementation details (database, http api). You can have inmemory implementations for testing purposes.